# A lot of variables with data JSONS in for-loop

Tags: python, json, loops, for-loop, variables

I try create for-loop to read data from json. But My code does not work. Please tell me how can i travel to right way.

```
with requests.Session() as session:
        session.headers.update(headers)

        response = session.get('https://api.allegro.pl/order/checkout-forms?limit=100')
        responsee = session.get('https://api.allegro.pl/order/checkout-forms?limit=100&offset=100')
        responseee = session.get('https://api.allegro.pl/order/checkout-forms?limit=100&offset=200')
        responseee3 = session.get('https://api.allegro.pl/order/checkout-forms?limit=100&offset=300')
        responseee4 = session.get('https://api.allegro.pl/order/checkout-forms?limit=100&offset=400')
        responseee5 = session.get('https://api.allegro.pl/order/checkout-forms?limit=100&offset=500')


        
        wyswietl =response.json()
        wyswietl2 = responsee.json()
        wyswietl3 = responseee.json()
        wyswietl4 = responseee3.json()
        wyswietl5 = responseee4.json()
        wyswietl6 = responseee5.json()
        
        for p in wyswietl['checkoutForms'],wyswietl2['checkoutForms'],wyswietl3['checkoutForms'],wyswietl4['checkoutForms'],wyswietl5['checkoutForms'],wyswietl6['checkoutForms']:
...
```

Comment: Where is the error message? What's the minimal reproducible example? One of the goals in programming is to minimise repeating of code.  Why not 1) create a function to do the search and 2) create a list of the urls you're requesting or 3) even better get the total number of results and then just create a loop to iterate through up to and including the final page.  What you don't have to do is create 6 different requests.

Comment: Your comment help me a lot. Thank you so much! I solve my problem with 2) option :)

Answer (score 0):

```
info = ['https://api.allegro.pl/order/checkout-forms?limit=100','https://api.allegro.pl/order/checkout-forms?limit=100&offset=100','https://api.allegro.pl/order/checkout-forms?limit=100&offset=200','https://api.allegro.pl/order/checkout-forms?limit=100&offset=300','https://api.allegro.pl/order/checkout-forms?limit=100&offset=400','https://api.allegro.pl/order/checkout-forms?limit=100&offset=500']
        for i in info:
            response = session.get(i)
            wyswietl = response.json()
        
            for p in wyswietl['checkoutForms']: ...
```